# Create custom entity on the fly from a SQL query

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'd like to create an entity from a custom SQL query. Is that possible with Entity Framework 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember now. [`ExecuteStoryQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx) will do just that.

See [Directly Executing Store Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358758.aspx)